# Nested layouts in admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I've started investigating admin-on-rest. It works fine for 'flat' REST-endpoints, e.g.:

`/posts/`

`/users/`

etc.
But how do I implement nesting? I mean if I click on some post-entry in 'posts' table - I want not the actual post to be opened in a `<Show>` view, but a list of it's comments (fetched from URL `/{postId}/comments`)? And I need also to keep the navigation functionality (some back-arrow button or hierarchy in the header to return to previous page).

Is this even possible with admin-or-rest?

Comment: That's the job of a custom restClient. Refers to the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client)

Comment: I'm not sure about it. `restClient` is about ways of fetching data, but not about displaying it. Otherwise could you please provide some sample for solving my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a list of comments for a post, use the `<ReferenceField>`. You can see an example in the demo: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/customers/77 (click on the "orders" and "reviews" tabs to see an embedded datagrid).

If you want to link to a filtered list of comments from the post list, you'll have to create a custom button component. Once again, you can find an example in the demo: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/segments/LinkToRelatedCustomers.js

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need :)